# ModSecurity on Apache : @pmFromFile, is there a document root path variable?

Tags: apache, mod-security

I'm trying to set rules for Mod-Security on Apache (Windows) in file modsecurity.conf

When using operator @pmFromFile, is it possible to use Apache variable %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} to set the path of the txt file ?

I have tried things like this, but its not recognized:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@pmFromFile %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/whitelist.txt" "phase:1,id:1,allow"
```

Is there a special syntax for that ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried with `%{env.DOCUMENT_ROOT}`? See the documentation: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#env

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have just tried your proposition with "@pmFromFile %{env.DOCUMENT_ROOT}/whitelist.txt" but it doesn't work neither. When i set the path by hand ( path/to/root/whitelist.txt ) modsecurity works well, but %{env.DOCUMENT_ROOT} doesn't seem to be recognized.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like `@pm` and `@pmfromFile` operators don't support macro expansions: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#user-content-pm

"Note : This operator does not support macro expansion (as of ModSecurity v2.9.1)."

Comment: Ok, so you can only set a "static" path with path/to/etc, no way to use a variable. Thank you very much airween to take time to look in the modsecurity doc, i didn't know what macro expansion means, so couldn't understand this note.

Comment: You are welcome. (If there is no more question related to this topic, could you make this as solved?)